# Perl regex directly escaping special characters

Tags: perl

A perl beginner here. I have been working on some simple one-liners to find and replace text in a file. I read about escaping all special characters with `\Q\E` or `quotemeta()` but found this only works when interpolating a variable. For example when I try to replace the part containing special characters directly, it fails. But when I store it in a scalar first it works. Of course, if I escape all the special character in backslashes it also works.

```
$ echo 'One$~^Three' | perl -pe 's/\Q$~^\E/Two/'
One$~^Three
$ echo 'One$~^Three' | perl -pe '$Sub=q($~^); s/\Q$Sub\E/Two/'
OneTwoThree
$ echo 'One$~^Three' | perl -pe 's/\$\~\^/Two/'
OneTwoThree
```

Can anyone explain this behavior and also show if any alternative exists that can directly quote special characters without using backslashes?

Comment: there are no good alternatives, which is why backslashes exist. :P

Comment: One-liners are much harder to get right than proper program files, with `use strict`, `use warnings` and proper variable declarations in place. I honestly don't see any reason ever to write one-line Perl program except that it is part of the Linux culture with throw-away piped bash command chains, and it is certainly not a good place to start learning the language. Put your Perl in a file and run it from an IDE: it will be very much simpler to understand and debug, much less likely to get you into bad coding habits, and the code will remain on disk for you to to open and run again if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpolation happens first, then `\Q`, `\U`, `\u`, `\L` and `\l`.

That means

```
"abc\Qdef$ghi!jkl\Emno"
```

is equivalent to

```
"abc" . quotemeta("def" . $ghi . "!jkl") . "mno"
```

So,

```
s/\Q$~^/Two/    # not ok   quotemeta($~ . "^")
s/\Q$Sub/Two/   # ok
s/\$\~\^/Two/   # ok
s/\$\Q~^/Two/   # ok
```

Comment: So only the presence of `$` would be a problem? If there are any other sequence of special characters like `(~^` it should work, right?

Comment: `@` can also start interpolation. You also can't escape the delimiter that way.